# Getting SettingWithCopyWarning when applying apply on a DataFrame Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I keep getting this warning but really do not know what should I change here:

```
C:\Users\3626416\Software\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:543:
    SettingWithCopyWarning:
        A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
        Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

See the caveats in the documentation: 
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

```
self.obj[item] = s
```

Here is my code:

```
df_pcl.loc[:,['Weight','Pieces','Cons','DeadWeight']] = df_pcl.loc[:,['Weight','Pieces','Cons','DeadWeight']] * pcl2docRtio
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause. Had to use df_pcl = source_df.loc[idx,:].copy() instead of df_pcl = source_df.loc[idx,:].